# How to evaluate the infinite series: $ \frac 1 {3\cdot6} + \frac 1 {3\cdot6\cdot9} +\frac 1 {3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot12}+\ldots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The infinite series is given by:

$$ \dfrac 1 {3\cdot6} + \dfrac 1 {3\cdot6\cdot9} +\dfrac 1 {3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot12}+\ldots$$

What I thought of doing was to split the general term as:

$$\begin{align} 
t_r &=  \dfrac 1 {3^{r+1}(r+1)!}\\\\
&= \dfrac {r+1 - r} {3^{r+1}(r+1)!}\\\\
&= \dfrac {1} {3^{r+1}\cdot r!} - \dfrac{r}{3^{r+1}(r+1)!}
\end{align}$$

But this doesn't seem to help.

**HINTS?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$e^x=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac{x^r}{r!}$$

Can you take it from here?

A strongly resembling sequence  $$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{1\le r<\infty}\frac{x^r}{r}$$ for $-1\le x<1$

Comment: Sheesh! Didn't even think that it was $e^x$. I kept on trying to bring in $e$ somehow, but this, I couldn't think. Thanks :D